# ubuntu низкая скорость интернета

Tags: ubuntu

Поставил ubuntu 16.04.4 и скорость от wi-fi не поднимается выше 600кб/с кто знает с чем может быть связано? Поставил xubuntu 16.04.4 скорость нормальная. Но хотелось как то на ubuntu остаться а что со скоростью делать не знаю.

Comment: Может вам использовать команду **ss**? More info: `man ss`

Comment: Ubuntu~xubuntu чем мера скрости берется?